# Grouping and remove from list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have following type

```
public class Parameter
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string PathType {get;set;}
}
```

My parameter list like:

```
List<Parameter> params = new List<Parameter>();
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="A", PathType ="path" });
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="B", PathType ="query" });
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="C", PathType ="path" });
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="C", PathType ="query" });
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="D", PathType ="path" });
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="D", PathType ="query" });
params.Add(new Parameter{ Name ="D", PathType ="body" });
```

I need to find parameters that have the same `Name` (like: `C` and `D`) where `PathType` equals `path` and `query`. Sorry for my English, it is a little bit difficult to explain. I want to find

```
 Name ="C", PathType ="path"
 Name ="C", PathType ="query"
 Name ="D", PathType ="path"
 Name ="D", PathType ="query"
```

Then remove all where `PathType = "query"`. Finally result should be

```
Name ="A", PathType ="path" 
Name ="B", PathType ="query"
Name ="C", PathType ="path" 
Name ="D", PathType ="path" 
Name ="D", PathType ="body"
```

My code

```
var groupedParams = params.GroupBy(a => a.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToDictionary(t => t.Key);
foreach (var parameter in params) {
    if (groupedParams.ContainsKey(parameter.Name)) {
        var temp = groupedParams[parameter.Name];
        if (temp.Count(x => x.PathType.ToLower() == "path") == 1 && temp.Count(x => x.PathType.ToLower() == "query") == 1) {
            params.Remove(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to group by name but remove only when there are path and query for that name.
Please suggest how can I do in in other way? Thanks

Comment: @SushilMate Thank but it is not duplicate

Comment: You can't modify collection what you using in foreach statement. If you want to delete elements from your collection use foreach (var parameter in params.ToArray()) but it's not best solution because you will get full copy of your array in memory

Comment: What do you mean Remove? I think you wanted to say Not To Select? Cause Remove means that you Delete data from your collection. If you want to delete - you can't modify any collection inside FOREACH because Enumerator has no priority (just read) and when you modify collection inside Foreach loop over that collection, your Enumerator becomes NOT eligible or actual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to group by name but remove only when there are path and query for that name. Please suggest how can I do in in other way?

If I were to assume that phrase is equal to this:

> How do I remove a parameter with `PathType="query"` from a collection, *if and only if* there's another parameter with the same `Name` AND `PathType="path"`?

Then you could do it with this statement:

```
params.RemoveAll(o => o.PathType == "query" && params.Any(p => p.Name == o.Name && p.PathType == "path"));
```

**Update**:

For case insensitive comparison (on `PathType`):

```
params.RemoveAll(o => o.PathType.Equals("query", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && params.Any(p => p.Name == o.Name && p.PathType.Equals("path", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: This might not remove the items where PathType = "Path"

Comment: Fair enough, did not read correctly... Best solution then, have my vote

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with this LINQ statement:

```
var cleanedParams = params.Where(p => p.PathType != "query" ||
    !params.Any(p2 => p2.Name == p.Name && p2.PathType != "query")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor: What do you mean it doesn't help? Raidri's solution gives the expected output. Are there any requirements you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 1):

I have some difficulty to understand your problem as it is not well stated.
So here is what i have understood. It has 2 questions:
Q1. Return those entries which has repeated names (e.g. c and d) where pathType has value query or path like you mentioned in your expected result.

```
Name ="C", PathType ="path"
Name ="C", PathType ="query"
Name ="D", PathType ="path"
Name ="D", PathType ="query"
```

if yes you can get it like:

```
var filteredList = param.Where(x => x.PathType == "query" || x.PathType == "path").ToList();
//Below list will have result.
var duplicateNameList = filteredList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Q2. Get the entries from the list where pathType =="query" or pathType=="path".

if yes here is the code:

```
 var result = param.Where(x => x.PathType != "query" && x.PathType!="path").ToList();
```

Let me know if i have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you can't use `params` as variable's name because it's C# instruction.

Next. As I understand you want to have cycles. Ok, as I noted above, you can't modify collection (`papram` in your case) inside `foreach` loop body. You can use something like this:

```
var groupedParams = _params.GroupBy(a => a.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToDictionary(t => t.Key);
int i = 0;
while (i != _params.Count)
{
    if (groupedParams.ContainsKey(parameter.Name))
    {
        var temp = groupedParams[parameter.Name];
        if (temp.Count(x => x.PathType.ToLower() == "path") == 1 && temp.Count(x => x.PathType.ToLower() == "query") == 1)
        {
            params.RemoveAt(i);
            continue;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

I've just rename `params` to `_params` to make it more correct. If `params` is just `Parametr[]` replace `_params.Count` with `_params.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the solution. My code :

```
var paramList = params.Where(x => x.PathType.Equals("path") || x.PathType.Equals("query"));
var groupedParams  = paramList.GroupBy(a => a.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToDictionary(t => t.Key);
foreach (var item in groupedParams) {
    var temp = item.Value.Count() > 1;
    if (temp) {
        var paramToDelete = operation.parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == item.Key.ToLower() && x.PathType == "query");
        if (paramToDelete != null) {
            operation.parameters.Remove(paramToDelete);
        }
    }
}
```